# Bluetooth card all of a sudden disappears?

Tags: linux, bluetooth

I'm on a 2011 8,3 MacBook Pro running Ubuntu 11.10 amd64.

I've been using the Bluetooth card in my machine perfectly for a long time. All of sudden, for no apparent reason, the Bluetooth device is gone. `hcitool dev` shows no devices at all.

What on earth happened? How can I find my Bluetooth card and get it working again? The only thing I did was install `b43` from a compat-wireless, as I had to compile it myself. Is there something I did wrong there? How can I tell what the problem is and fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is, as it turns out, an Apple problem. You need to reset the Intel SMC [as according to this guide.](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3964?viewlocale=en_US)

Simply follow these steps:

1. Shut down the computer.
2. When it's off and is plugged into a power source, hold the left Shift, Control, and Alt/Option buttons down. Then, hold down the power button.
3. The computer won't turn on, don't worry. Hold all 4 buttons for about 5 seconds, then let them go at the same time.
4. Next, hit the power button.

It should work, now. Wow, Apple, wow.

Comment: is this only for apple computers ? or there are other tricks on pc hosts ?

Comment: Usually, if I have a problem with Bluetooth on a Desktop, it helps to shut down the PC, turn off the power supply, wait a bit, then flip it back on again and restart. Usually has to do with an EFI/BIOS problem with the Bluetooth hardware.